# Create dependency statistics on not reference columns

Tags: postgresql

Assume following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE main
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
);

CREATE TABLE apple
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    main_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES main(id)
);

CREATE TABLE orange
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    main_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES main(id)
);

CREATE TABLE main_history
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    history_valid_from TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    history_valid_to TIMESTAMPTZ
);

CREATE TABLE apple_history
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    main_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES main(id), -- main_history does not have a PK
    history_valid_from TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    history_valid_to TIMESTAMPTZ
);

CREATE TABLE orange_history
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    main_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES main(id), -- main_history does not have a PK
    history_valid_from TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    history_valid_to TIMESTAMPTZ
);
```

So there is a root (main) and two tables which reference on it. The referenced table hold max. 20 records (in 99% of the cases) for each main record.

The problem starts when I try to retreive the history:

```
SELECT * FROM main_history
LEFT JOIN apple_history ON apple_history.main_id = main_history.id AND
  apple_history.history_valid_from <= '2021-12-20T10:46:52.482620Z' AND
  (apple_history.history_valid_to IS NULL OR '2021-12-20T10:46:52.482620Z' < apple_history.history_valid_to)
LEFT JOIN orange_history ON orange_history.main_id = main_history.id AND
  orange_history.history_valid_from <= '2021-12-20T10:46:52.482620Z' AND
  (orange_history.history_valid_to IS NULL OR '2021-12-20T10:46:52.482620Z' < orange_history.history_valid_to)
WHERE
  main_history.id IN (1,2,3,4) AND
  main_history.history_valid_from <= '2021-12-20T10:46:52.482620Z' AND
  (main_history.history_valid_to IS NULL OR '2021-12-20T10:46:52.482620Z' < main_history.history_valid_to)
```

The point is: I'm joining now over a non-referencing column. PostgreSQL overestimates the rows up to 20.000 times (see https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/oIF).

Then I tried to

```
SET enable_hashjoin = off; SET enable_mergejoin = off
```

because I knew that there are not that much rows --> then it went down to 100msec.

When I change the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM main
LEFT JOIN apple_history ON apple_history.main_id = main_history.id AND
  apple_history.history_valid_from <= '2021-12-20T10:46:52.482620Z' AND
  (apple_history.history_valid_to IS NULL OR '2021-12-20T10:46:52.482620Z' < apple_history.history_valid_to)
LEFT JOIN orange_history ON orange_history.main_id = main_history.id AND
  orange_history.history_valid_from <= '2021-12-20T10:46:52.482620Z' AND
  (orange_history.history_valid_to IS NULL OR '2021-12-20T10:46:52.482620Z' < orange_history.history_valid_to)
WHERE
  main.id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

It can use the original statitics - everything works fine.

My question: Can I create manual statistics for JOINing not REFERENCESed columns? Goal: use main_history as main table in the query without forcing JOIN strategies

Answer (score 0):

You need some indexes.

To replicate 100ms performance all you need to do is create an index on main_history (main_id, valid_from, valid_to) and you should be set.

But why, though? Ok, so when you query `main_history WHERE main_history.Id IN (1,2,3,4)` postgres

- doesn't know how many rows will match
- doesn't know where the rows are on disk/in memory

It has no choice but to scan the entire main_history table to find the rows you're looking for. And the same goes for apples_history/oranges_history. It cannot possibly know where the corresponding main_ids are, nor how many there are. Full scans are needed, and Hash-joins are the best choices (since data isn't ordered)

So to help it along, you create indexes on the referenced/referencing columns. They give count and order, and will help postgres choose the correct plan.

Comment: I added an index on main_id. Also created index on main_id + history_valid_from / to. But no effect. Maybe it works with statistics?
What we do as hotfix: we joined via main and did a left join on main_history - now its very fast (~50msec) but it was quite a hack to make it work in hibernate because two tables in one entity + filter is beyond of hibernates comfort ;-)